# I want to capture a set of 5 consecutive lines from a file where after my condition matches by using for each loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$ourfilesdata = Get-Content "P:\myfiles\details.txt" 

    foreach ($i in $ourfilesdata )
        {
        if ( $i -match '\Mobile\b') {continue)
          {
          Write-Output "$i"
          }
        }
```

**My input is like 50 lines **

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbb
Request
Mobile
Sim
datacard
internet
ccccccc
dddddddd
fffffff
```

**Output**

```
mobile
sim
datacard
internet
```

**Note** :- These input  lines are horizontal fashion in my file

Comment: You could use Import-CSV which will user spaces as well as commas or any other delimiter.  You can use Select-String which has a pattern property which uses Regex for filtering and a Path Property to read from a file.

Comment: Can you post a couple of sample of the of input data (at least 10 lines) and the column names.

Comment: version-specific tags like [tag:powershell-2.0] are only for bugs/issues that *only* occur/apply to that specific version. Never use them for general issues. And please learn how to format properly with markdown, your formatting is terrible and produce wrong and unreadable output due to `_` being treated as formatting and not as a character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select-String  "P:\myfiles\details.txt" -Pattern 'Request\b' -Context 0,5 |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Line,$_.Context.PostContext}
```

This will 100% works and thank me later :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but see if this is what you're looking for:

```
#Current working directory
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$MainPath = $PSScriptRoot += "\"

$ourfilesdata = $MainPath + "Randomc.txt"

$ourfilesdata

$search = '\\Mobile\\b'
$GetLine = Get-Content $ourfilesdata | Select-String $search

$GetLine.LineNumber

$GetLine
```